# Snapshotting a `UIView` crashes the app with `NSInvalidArgumentException` "[_UIReplicantView _isSymbolImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimage, xcode11.4

Hi guys i have just updated XCode to version 11.4 from the app store and when i try to snapshot a `UIView` on iOS 13.4 like this:

```swift
extension UIView {

    func snapshot(at scale: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {

        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: bounds.size)
        let image = renderer.image { [weak self] context in
            self?.drawHierarchy(in: self?.bounds ?? .zero, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }

        return image
    }
}
```

or like that:

```swift
extension UIView {

    func snapshotOld(at scale: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, scale)
        guard let currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }
        layer.render(in: currentContext)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

and set the resulting image to `UIImageView` like that:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private weak var imageView: UIImageView!


    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let image = view.snapshot
        imageView.image = image
    }
}

extension UIView {

    @objc var snapshot: UIImage? {
        snapshot(at: 3.0)
//        snapshotOld(at: 3.0)
    }
}
```

i get:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_UIReplicantView _isSymbolImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x115907c00'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1ad52c164 0x1ad240c1c 0x1ad42a7e0 0x1b16a5b6c 0x1ad53085c 0x1ad532b60 0x1b1af6cdc 0x1b1af714c 0x1b1af0b30 0x1025061a8 0x102506270 0x1b1010880 0x1b10112cc 0x1b0f25658 0x1b167fc10 0x1b166f13c 0x1b16a088c 0x1ad4a6c54 0x1ad4a18e4 0x1ad4a1d84 0x1ad4a1660 0x1b78b2604 0x1b167615c 0x102507f78 0x1ad31d1ec)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I get this both in simulator and on a real device.

Do you guys have any idea why is this happening? I suspect it is a XCode 11.4 bug because this code worked nicely on the older versions

[Here is a sample project if you would like to try it out on your machine](https://github.com/stoqn4opm/UIReplicantViewCrashExample)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not calling the method you think you are. You have two choices:

- Change `snapshot` to `snapshott` everywhere (or some other nonambiguous alternative).
- Or else, remove the `@objc` designation.

Do either of those things, and all will be well.

Comment: Yes, this is based on running your code. I'll submit this back to you as a fork.

Comment: it works i was changing the method names not the computed variable name. Thanks a lot :) But what did i call then ? Really weird

Comment: Submitted this as a pull request, check your github repo.

Comment: Yeah, well, this is like what happens when you call a view property `firstResponder` and expose it to Objective-C. Your whole app breaks. :) Cocoa has taken a lot of names and there is no namespacing, so it's your job to pick names that don't overlap Cocoa's names. Which is hard to do, because you don't know what they are.

Comment: i won't merge your fork, so that people that look at this in the future will see what the issue was and how you fixed it. Here is a link to matt's pull request https://github.com/stoqn4opm/UIReplicantViewCrashExample/pull/1/files

Comment: Open pull request are bad. Please pull, test, and merge, so I can close my fork.  Git holds the commit so people can still see it.