# Xcode 11.4 not allowing to use instance variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, instance-variables, xcode11.4

i have Just In time property, which was working fine but now xcode 11.4 started complaining about it. please look at following code

```
- (UITextField *)searchTextField
{
    if (!_searchTextField)
    {
        _searchTextField = [self firstSubViewOfKindOfClass:[UITextField class]];
    }
    return _searchTextField;
}
```

**Error :Use of undeclared identifier '_searchTextField'**

i have a property defined for it like below

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField  *searchTextField;
```

Comment: Which line is the error reported on? The `if (!_searchTextField)` line?

Comment: WFM. How/where is `firstSubViewOfKindOfClass` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a name clash. You cannot *define* a `searchTextField` because there already *is* a `searchTextField` (in iOS 13):

```
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchbar/3175433-searchtextfield
```

So you could just delete your code, as it isn't needed in iOS 13. Or if you need to support iOS 12 and earlier, you could give your property a different name that doesn't clash.

Comment: I’m not clear on that, but it seems to be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60870129/snapshotting-a-uiview-crashes-the-app-with-nsinvalidargumentexception-uir/60871913#60871913. The Cocoa namespace, or the nature of its exposure, seems to have changed.